# Google Analytics Mobile (ipod/iphone) Custom Variables tracking

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-analytics

It's a bit of time I'm using analytics in my iPhone applications and I find it very useful...but apparently it seems to give me only the ability to track pageviews and events.

I just would like to know if there's a way to track even custom variables defined by me, as web analytics does.

I.e. I'm releasing the new version of my app and I would like to define a variable that reports me the version of the application (instead of defining a new action or pageview to track it).

the standard js api to handle that should be: _setCustomVar(index, name, value, opt_scope).
Is there a way to figure it out even on the mobile version of analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late, but yes : custom variables on iOS google analytics library is available since v1.1.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the setCustomVar() function should come before the trackPageview(). The information is only sent to Google Analytics during a pageview or an event, so keep that in mind when placing the code on your site.

Answer (score 0):

Localytics provides exactly this functionality.  For any event in your application, such as a button click or a level completion you may record the event as happening and associate with a Dictionary of keys and values which are reported back as event attributes.  For an example and some more details, check out the blog post:

http://www.localytics.com/blog/post/new-feature-explored-event-attributes/